# Конвертер Markdown в HTML и обратно на C# или JS

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, markdown

Нужен конвертер Markdown в HTML **и обратно** средствами C# или JS, есть ли готовые решения?

Я хочу сделать так: Пользователь создает текст Markdown или HTML на выбор (кол-во html тегов ограничено функциональностью Markdown). В процессе работы он может переключаться с одного способа создания разметки на другой. Для этого мне нужен конвертер в обе стороны.

Comment: Туда — https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown. Обратно невозможно.

Comment: @VladD нет ничего невозможного. Непонятно только как отличить теги, которые сделал конвертер от тегов, которые напишет пользователь. Я думал уже есть готовое решение (как-нить через анализ вложенности тегов)

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что это возможно? У вас в голове есть алгоритм?

Comment: @VladD Я собирался экранировать все символы при конвертации в html. Конвертировать обратно меняя не экранированные теги на аналоги. Например h1 менять на #, удаляя закрывающий тег.

Comment: А что делать с кодом, который создаёт разметку через JS?

Comment: @VladD Я хочу сделать так: Пользователь создает текст Markdown или HTML на выбор (кол-во html тегов ограничено). В процессе работы он может переключаться с одного способа создания разметки на другой. Для этого мне нужен конвертер в обе стороны. Создавать разметку через js я не планировал.

Comment: Тогда у вас не HTML, а _ваше_ подмножество HTML. Это важно, мне кажется, имеет смысл объяснить это в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Туда можно сделать так

1. https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown
2. https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagedown/ (это на SO используется, но не знаю насколько он актуален )

Обратно

1. https://domchristie.github.io/turndown/

Comment: А что делать с `<ol start="100">`? Это поддерживается в HTML и не поддерживается в markdown.

Comment: @VladD я и не говорю что эти решения покрывают 100%, это то что есть. Вообще в HTML может быть всё что угодно, этот формат шире чем markdown.

Comment: Понимаю. Возможно, имеет смысл отметить это в ответе, чтобы читатели не надеялись на _полную_ конвертацию HTML.

Comment: @VladD я думаю тут важно не любой html конвертировать, а тот набор с которым работает markdown. Конечно для коректной работы надо будет ещё много чего сделать, например не давать создавать лишние html конструкции, но это уже за рамками данного вопроса.

Comment: @VladD я не планирую поддерживать что-либо, что не поддерживает Markdown. Не поддерживаемые теги будут выводится как обычный текст. Этот ответ решает мою проблему (по крайней мере пока)

Comment: @mirypoko: Одинаковые конструкции markdown разными конвертерами могут по-разному конвертироваться в HTML. Поэтому «то, что поддерживает Markdown» определено неоднозначно.